# From Mockito to Mockk: how to pass constructor parameter?

Tags: kotlin, mockito, mockk

I have this Mockito usage:

```
var mockMyClass = mock<MyClass>(useConstructor = UseConstructor.withArguments(myObject)) {
        on { go() } doReturn "something"
    }
```

And I'm trying to rewrite it with Mockk:

```
var mockMyClass = mockk<MyClass>() {
        every { go() } returns "something"
    }
```

How do I pass the constructor parameter, please?

Comment: Check out the doc [here](https://github.com/mockk/mockk#constructor-mocks). It's in mockk version `1.11.0` and above.

Comment: Actually, now I see my question does not make sense. I would delete it, but since that doc may be helpful for other situation and I understand now that it could really be an answer, I will let it be and upvote the comment. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Even better, you could answer your question which can be helpful for someone seeking the same migration.